# How to mimic a dictionary for unit testing with pytest

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

I want to test the following function using pytest:

```
def validate_account(number):
    try:
    
        number = int(number)
    
    except:
    
        raise ValueError("Please enter a valid account number")
    
    if int(number) not in accounts_dict:
    
        raise Exception("Pleaseeee enter a valid account number.")
    
    return number
```

`accounts_dict` gets items added later on. For unit testing with pytest, how can I mimic this dictionary to test per whether or not a number is in dictionary?

As of now, `accounts_dict` is empty. And, when I try to assert validate_account("1") == 1, it's throwing the 'Pleaseeee' exception (not in accounts_dict dictionary). I have googled and tried few different options like `accounts_dict = Mock(return_value =n)`, `accounts_dict.get('1') != None` etc., but they are not helping. Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: How is `accounts_dict` defined and how do you import and call `validate_account()` in your test?

Comment: That's a good indication that your function needs `accounts_dict` as an argument (dependency injection).

Comment: Whenever a user wants to open an account, it creates an account class object with username and password and adds the object to accounts_dict by assigning an account number. Number is incremented when opening another account. Validate_account() use to check whether a user input account number is valid to allow them to perform activities on the respective account. I am doing this for my learner project and stuck at how to test it before actually creating account using the main code.

Comment: How can I do dependency injection? I have tried creating a dictionary  with a function under pytest.fixture and passing that function as an argument to test_validate_account but it didnt work.

Comment: You need to mock the `accounts_dict` variable *where that function gets it from*. If that's a constant in a module, say, `module`, you would have to `import module` and monkeypatch `module.accounts_dict`. If it's a member if a class, you'd have to monkeypatch it in the class, etc. Creating an `accounts_dict` variable in your test just creates a new variable that the function you're testing cannot see.

Comment: If you can't figure it out from these comments, please share more code: tell use exactly how and where `accounts_dict` is declared for your function to see.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know it before. I went on creating variable in my test function and it did not work. Adding it as argument to the actual function worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dict is an argument (as it should) you can do this

```
def validate_account(number, accounts_dict):
...

def test_validate_account__valid():
    assert validate_account("1", {1:True}) == 1

def test_validate_account__invalid():
    with pytest.raises(Exception):
        validate_account("1", {2:True})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was stuck for hours yesterday unable to pass test_validate_account. Adding it as an argument for validate_account() and doing the same at places it is called worked. My tests are passing too as I can now give made up dict values like you showed.

Comment: That's why good practices pay off. If this is a solution for your problem please accept the answer.